# Where should I put the update sql action after the form submit (Symfony / Sylius)

Tags: symfony, sylius

Newbie question:

I have an entity `customer` with id, fieldA, fieldB and fieldC

There's a form which could update fieldA, fieldB.

After the form submitted, I want to add a function to check if fieldA and fieldB  are equal, fieldC change to 1.

Where should I put the function at? Obviously not under Entity and Form. Should I write a new controller (how to trigger the changes and do the action? add a listener?)?

Comment: please show your current efforts, it's a bit hard to explain Symfony / Sylius basics based on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is to handle it in Form:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
```

...

```
$builder
            ...
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getForm();

                if ($data->getFieldA() === $data->getFieldB()) {
                    $data->setFieldC(1);
                }
                $event->getForm()->setData();
            })
        ;
```

Comment: Changed a bit to below:

`$data = $event->getData();

if ($data->getFieldA() == $data->getFieldB()) {
    $data->setFieldC(1);
    $event->setData($data);
}`